# array of callbacks as Promise?

Tags: javascript, rpc, yui

I am working through some old legacy code dealing with network requests using RPC/YUI library.  It essentially creates  tags to handle network requests.  There are no promises for these.Also, because of IE11 support, we cannot use the native Promise object.  Our build process does not utilize any NPM dependencies, so we cannot use any babel related polyfills.

There is a bug I am working on to fix that the argument `ignoreError` gets overwritten each time another function calls the same function....obviously!  We have multiple functions calling this network request function library.  Sometimes we want to ignore an error, sometimes we do not.

What is the ideal way to store the multiple requests made and their respective error callbacks so the appropriate item is called?

example:

```
var rpcUrl,
rpcRetries,
rpcIgnoreError;

// main function that sets some globals:
rpc: function(url, retries, ignoreError) {
  rpcUrl = url;
  rpcRetries = retries;
  rpcIgnoreError = ignoreError;
  this.doRpc();
},
// calls the YUI library to initialize network script:
doRpc: function() {
  YAHOO.util.Get.script(rpcUrl, {
    onFailure: function() {
      this.callbackError(true);
    },
    timeout: 55000
  });
},
// YUI callback
callbackError: function(retry) {
  if (retry && rpcRetries > 0) {
    rpcRetries = rpcRetries - 1;
    this.doRpc();
  } else {
    // ** how do i know this error handling is for the script which failed?
    if (!rpcIgnoreError) {
      this.populateFormStatus(6);
    }
  }
},
```

now, we have multiple functions calling `rpc()` such as:

```
sendConfig: function() {
  this.rpc(urlForEndpoint, 3, true);
},
sendUser: function() {
  this.rpc(urlForEndpoint, 3, false);
},
sendWidget: function() {
  this.rpc(urlForEndpoint, 3, false);
},
```

I am concerned making an array of callbacks will not guarantee that each item is handled with its respective handler.

I could do something like create a map constant:

```
var RPC_ERR_CB = {
    sendConfig: false,
    sendUser: true,
    sendWidget: true
};
```

// and then in the `onFailure` callback, I can read the `src` of the script tag:

```
...
doRpc: function() {
  YAHOO.util.Get.script(rpcUrl, {
    onFailure: function() {
      var hasCB = Object.keys(RPC_ERR_CB).some(function(item) {
        return arguments[0].src.indexOf(RPC_ERR_CB[item]) <= 0;
     });
      if (hasCB) {
        this.callbackError(true);
      }
    },
    timeout: 55000
  });
},
```

Hope this makes sense...THANKS!

Comment: Do you need to wait until every call has been resolved? - Do they resolve sequentially or parallel

Comment: No we do not need this functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am concerned making an array of callbacks will not guarantee that each item is handled with its respective handler."? There is just one handler as far as I can see (`callbackError`).

Comment: You can simply do `this.doRpc (ignoreError)` and `this.callbackError (true, ignoreError)`

Comment: @FK82, yes there is 1 handler, but there can be multiple sources with individual callbacks.  in this case, if item 2 errors first, it might trigger item 1's callback, if there's an array

Comment: But you have the same problem with all of your variables, you might want to store the url, alongside those options inside of an object, keep it somewhere in your class instance, or as you proposed in an extra lookup.

Comment: A lookup with callbacks and the desired behaviour would be the easiest way i guess, like the solution you proposed, maybe keep the callback in the same lookup.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is, but you can easily pass the url to the error handler since it is closed in `doRpc` (you pass a callback function to the `onFailure` property which closes `rpcUrl`). So just change the callback to `function() { this.callbackError(rpcUrl, true); }`. Now you know which script's error handler was triggered when `callbackError` is called.

Comment: I think we're all saying just about the same thing now :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not able to use Promises or ES6 Classes, your options become somewhat limited. If at all possible, I would recommend biting the bullet on getting a Babel transpilation process so you can take advantage of newer features without needing to drop IE11 support.

As it is now though, ideally you don't want to track every request in a global variable somewhere. You can handle each transaction independently by creating each request as a self-contained object:

```js
function RpcRequest (url, retries, ignoreError) {
  this.url = url
  this.retries = retries
  this.ignoreError = ignoreError
}

RpcRequest.prototype.send = function() {
  YAHOO.util.Get.script(this.url, {
    onFailure: function() {
      this.callbackError(true);
    },
    timeout: 55000
  });
}

RpcRequest.prototype.callbackError = function(retry) {
  if (retry && this.retries > 0) {
    this.retries = this.retries - 1;
    this.send();
  } else {
    if (!this.ignoreError) {

      // ...

    }
  }
}

// Somewhere else, initiate a request
var requestOne = new RpcRequest("http://blah", 3, false)
requestOne.send()
```

Something I noted when looking over your code: the code that's creating the request has no idea whether the request succeeded or not. And when you have an error, the calling context doesn't know anything about that error. I took a look at the library you mentioned, and it does appear to have some context that you can pass along.

If I were to rewrite this a little bit, I'd do something like this to bubble the error up to your calling context:

```js
RpcRequest.prototype.send = function(callback) {
  YAHOO.util.Get.script(this.url, {
    onFailure: function(context) {
      if( this.ignoreError ) {
        context.ignoredError = true
        callback(null, context);
        return;
      }

      var retError = new Error('Failure doing something!');
      retError.context = context;

      callback(retError);
    },
    onSuccess: function(context) {
      callback(null, context);
    },
    timeout: 55000
  });
}

// Somewhere else in the code...
sendWidget: function() {
  var request = new RpcRequest(urlForEndpoint, 3, false)
  request.send(function(err, result) {
    if( err ) {
      console.error('Failed at doing a widget thing:', err.context);
      // maybe even:
      // throw err;
      return;
    }

    if( result.ignoredError ) {
      console.warn('Ignored an error on the widget thing:', result);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Success on the widget thing!', result);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the values into `doRpc`, then you can pass it to `callbackError` or handle it in `doRpc` (like your example code at the end).  This will prevent the global variable from changing on you.